# How to save the state of the application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I'm working on a project in which I'm using oauth to authenticate with peoples stripe account. Part of this process is to send the user off to the stripe website, and then after they log in they are sent back to my application. The problem I'm having is that the stripe authentication is part of a set up process. So I'd like them to return to the place they were before they were sent away, i.e the same page and the state of the form they were in to be the same.

What would be the best way for me to do this, I've thought about saving the form state in the session, the problem with this is it requires a lot of awkward parsing, and can be quite brittle.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please *show us your code*. What library are you using? How are you sending the user to Stripe?

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a database record before you go to Stripe keying with a GUID and then store the GUID in the session. Then when you come back you can load the database record and recreate whatever you need.

Comment: Exactly - the key is to make a checkout as a set of seperate steps instead of not persisting anything until after the payment is done which is very brittle.

Answer (score 1):

When redirecting the user to the OAuth form on Stripe's site, you can pass a [`state`](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-reference#get-authorize-request) variable. Stripe will pass back the same variable when redirecting the user back to your return URI.